# Python Camelot PDF - UnicodeEncodeError when using Stream flavor, on Windows

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-camelot

Python 3.7 on Windows 10. Camelot 0.8.2

I'm using the following code to convert a pdf file to HTML:

```
import camelot
import os
 
def CustomScript(args):
    path_to_pdf = "C:\PDFfolder\abc.pdf"        
    folder_to_pdf = os.path.dirname(path_to_pdf)
    tables = camelot.read_pdf(os.path.normpath(path_to_pdf), flavor='stream', pages='1-end')
    tables.export(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(folder_to_pdf,"temp","foo.html")), f='html')
    return CustomScriptReturn.Empty();
```

I receive the following error at the `tables.export` line:

> "UnicodeEncodeError -'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2010'
> in position y: character maps to undefined.

This code runs without issue on Mac.  This error seems to pertain to Windows, which is the environment I will need to run this on.

I have now spent two entire days researching this error **ad nauseum** - I have tried many of the solutions offered here on Stack Overflow from the several posts related to this.  The error persists. The problem with adding the lines of code suggested in all the solutions is that they're all arguments to be added to vanilla Python methods.  These arguments are not available to the Camelot's `export` method.

**EDIT 1:** Updated post to specify which line is throwing the error.

**EDIT 2:** PDF file used: http://tsbde.texas.gov/78i8ljhbj/Fiscal-Year-2014-Disciplinary-Actions.pdf

**EDIT 3:** Here is the full Traceback from Windows console:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 18, in
> <module>
>     tables.export(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(folder_to_pdf, "foo.html")), f='html')   File
> "C:\Users\stpete\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\camelot\core.py",
> line 737, in export
>     self._write_file(f=f, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\stpete\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\camelot\core.py",
> line 699, in _write_file
>     to_format(filepath)   File "C:\Users\stpete\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\camelot\core.py",
> line 636, in to_html
>     f.write(html_string)   File "C:\Users\stpete\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py",
> line 19, in encode
>     return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2010' in
> position 5737: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: I ran the code and. it generated 8 html files for me. I did not get any error. I am running on mac. A few changes i made are : `tables.export("tempfoo.html", f='html')` instead of reading the entire path. Did you test with basic file name instead of path?

Comment: I said in my post that this works on Mac, I need it to work on Windows. Also see the title of the post.

Comment: Duh!! My bad. I have a mac. Let me see if I can setup a windows system to try this out. Wonder what the difference is between mac & windows.

Comment: i know its going to sound silly but did you install Ghostscrip?

Comment: Yes it’s installed and the script works when you run Camelot in the default mode (called Lattice, which is achieved by removing `flavor=‘stream’`) so the installation of Camelot is fine.

Comment: @jdaz no issue with the slashes as it works in Lattice mode (see above comment).

Comment: I can't download the PDF. Please provide a valid URL.

Comment: @Anakin87 the url is valid.  Are you outside of the US?  It may be that the site blocks IP's outside the US.

Comment: yes I am in Europe

Comment: Ok.  Unfortunately I'm not allowed to upload the PDF here directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are facing is related to the method `camelot.core.Table.to_html`:

```
def to_html(self, path, **kwargs):
"""Writes Table to an HTML file.
For kwargs, check :meth:`pandas.DataFrame.to_html`.
Parameters
----------
path : str
    Output filepath.
"""
html_string = self.df.to_html(**kwargs)
with open(path, "w") as f:
    f.write(html_string)
```

Here, the file to be written should be opened with UTF-8 encoding and it is not.

This is my solution, which uses a monkey patch to replace original camelot method:

```
import camelot
import os

# here I define the corrected method
def to_html(self, path, **kwargs):
    """Writes Table to an HTML file.
    For kwargs, check :meth:`pandas.DataFrame.to_html`.
    Parameters
    ----------
    path : str
        Output filepath.
    """
    html_string = self.df.to_html(**kwargs)
    with open(path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(html_string)

# monkey patch: I replace the original method with the corrected one
camelot.core.Table.to_html=to_html

def CustomScript(args):
    path_to_pdf = "C:\PDFfolder\abc.pdf"        
    folder_to_pdf = os.path.dirname(path_to_pdf)
    tables = camelot.read_pdf(os.path.normpath(path_to_pdf), flavor='stream', pages='1-end')
    tables.export(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(folder_to_pdf,"temp","foo.html")), f='html')
    return CustomScriptReturn.Empty();
```

I tested this solution and it works for Python 3.7, Windows 10, Camelot 0.8.2.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your contribution.  Just so I'm clear, I should include all of the above code in MY script - I should not be editing the code in `camelot.core.py`... is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is a monkey patch: at the runtime, you locally replace this method in your script.
Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Ok great, I'm ok with monkey patches, and I've already reported this issue to the Camelot dev, so hopefully they'll address it.  I will try your suggestion here shortly, and report back asap.

Comment: This works perfectly.  You've allowed me to breathe a sigh of relief after 4 straight days of trying to get this to work.  In addition, I didn't know until today that you could do "temporary overrides" of existing methods.  This is really great.  Gladly awarding these rep points to you.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `UnicodeEncodeError`, which in this case means that the output to be written to file contains a character than cannot be encoded in the default encoding for your platform, cp1252.

camelot does not seem to handle setting an encoding when [writing to an html file](https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot/blob/705473198f18512a116b1b72c27469103c3d24e8/camelot/core.py#L634).

A workaround might be to set the [PYTHONIOENCODING](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) environment variable to "UTF-8" when running your program:

```
C:\> set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 && python myprog.py
```

to force outputting the file(s) with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me exactly where I should be putting the `PYTHONIOENCODING` line? At the top of the script?

Comment: You do in in the cmd prompt (assuming that you are calling your program via the cmd prompt).  I've edited the answer to make this clearer (and more cmd-friendly).  Se also https://superuser.com/a/1049433/1001855

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  This isn't working, unfortunately.  When I run `C:\> set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 python myprog.py `, nothing happens, it just immediately jumps to a new command prompt.  As an FYI, I use PyCharm for development, and I get the same error whether I run it or debug it from within there, or run it from the Windows command line.

Comment: Also, in PyCharm, I adjusted both the Global and Project encoding settings to UTF-8, and still get the error.

Comment: Added full traceback to original post.  Wondering if this can be addressed inside the camelot files somewhere?

Comment: Amended again the "&&" ought to work.  I suspect the pycharm settings may only affect source code encoding; however it may have options for setting environment variables too.

Comment: Sorry, `set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 && python myprog.py` also does not work.  The script will run in this case, but I get the same error.  At this point I believe the solution to reside in modifications to either my script code, or Camelot's code.